# I don't get zip() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am sure this is a very basic question and I have checked the web for answers but alas none has come up.

I am learning python 3.5 and I have installed Anaconda. I am trying to learn about and use the built-in function zip() but when I type something like (in my Jupiter notebook)

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
zip(a,b)
```

I get `<zip at 0xXXXXX>`as the output, where XXXXX is some (random) set of characters.  I was expecting

```
[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

as the output.  Is there something wrong or are my expectations incorrect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

In python 3 zip returns an iterator over the zipped values, use:

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 4):

In python 3 you nearly always get a generator object from operations such as `zip` or `range`.

This produces less memory overhead,  as no big iterable is created,  holding all the needed values.

If you want to get the list,  call `list` on the generator.

```
>>> l = list(zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
```

However, this will give you a list of tuples:

```
>>> l
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

If you want to get a list of lists,  use a list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [list(t) for t in zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])]
```